# Naming conventions of linking tables, and substring_index

Tags: mysql, indexing, substring, naming

I have a dbase named my_contacts, and consists of items like, f_name, l_name, location, interests, seeking,  gender, status, etc. this is a school project and am just learning mysql. I have created tables to split up items like a gender table consisting of m and f; as there will be a many to one relationship, and the others I split off were seeking , interests, status (married, divorced, etc), interests and seeking (friends, new job, etc).

I am pretty clear on what my pks all need to be ( I created a pk in ea table with a naming convention of things like id_gender, id_status, id_seeking, etc.

What I am unclear about is what to name my linking tables (which if I understand correctly will hold my foreign keys from the 2 tables they link, are there any naming conventions or suggestions? I thought about something like “contacts_link_gender”, “contacts_link_status”, etc.

Also is there a good tutorial somewhere about using mysqls “create a new eer model”, I am using murachs latest mysql book, but while a good book they tend to leave out way to much for someone just learning, the teach was showing us but hes very short and to the point and I am not a programmer, never wanted to be but its one of the last classes for the degree.

Oh also one more thing, when I take the fields like interests or seeking and split them up using substring_index I get dupes in some of my fields (interest_1, interest_2) and I don’t know how to fix it, I will include my substring code at the bottom
Again thanks in advance! 
Any and all advice is welcome

```
SELECT  distinct id, 
        first_name, 
        last_name,
        substring_index(location, ' ', 2) as city,
        substring_index(location, ' ',-1) as state,
        substring_index(interests, ' ', 1) as interest_1,
        substring_index(interests, ' ', -1) as interest_2,
        substring_index(seeking, ' ', 3) as seeking_1,
        substring_index(seeking, ' ', -3) as seeking_2
FROM my_contacts…..
```

Comment: Please avoid the wall of text.

Comment: Paragraphs! Take a breath once in a while.

Comment: Had to edit that the wall of text was just too hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Create separate fields for separate data. Do not pile things into a single field just because.

This example violates a lot of rules, the [Zero, One or Infinite Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) and most [database normalization rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) in particular, so I think you're doing more harm than good by reading that book if that's what's proposed as a good database design.

For an academic approach to MySQL, and SQL in general, you probably need to understand more of the theory of how to organize data and then learn to apply them by learning the relevant MySQL statements. `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT FROM` are the basics here.

[Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/) might be a bit too intense for you at this point, but you can learn proper normalization techniques by example. You could try and find some [references on the subject](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Relational_Database_Design/Normalization).

A better approach might be to post your schema on [the code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and get feedback on your particular design.

Comment: I will post the schema later, no I am not putting fields together, I am separating them ie: in the interests col "friends, motorcycles" becomes interest_1 "friends"  interest_2 "motorcycles". I completely understand create table, insert into, select from, where, order by, etc. I think you misunderstand my post

Comment: If you're not putting them together it's not clear why you'd need `SUBSTRING_INDEX` then. That sort of thing should be done in your application prior to insertion in the database.

Comment: it's a TEACHING exercise, we are not creating the db, just learning how to manipulate data. for putting things together I would use the CONCAT comd, I am taking things like "city, st" AND splitting that up into 2 col,current exercise is splitting up those and creating a table with all the city's in 1 table and then create a linking table (the exercise is all about fk/pk) other than that I cant tell you why they are doing it the way,maybe teach us to modify an existing db if and when we get a job. My ? about the SUBSTRING_INDEX has to do with why am I getting dupes in some of the col

Comment: umns, I cant see that posting the original my_contacts code will help as that entire code was given to us, does that help?

Comment: I will leave this up for a bit, but I am going to split the question up into indiv questions, apparently it is too many questions in one post